# Get webpage links using rvest

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I tried using rvest to extract links of "VAI ALLA SCHEDA PRODOTTO" form this website:

https://www.asusworld.it/series.asp?m=Notebook#db_p=2

My R code:

```
library(rvest)

page.source <- read_html("https://www.asusworld.it/series.asp?m=Notebook#db_p=2")
version.block <- html_nodes(page.source, "a") %>% html_attr("href")
```

However, I can't get any links look like "/model.asp?p=2340487". How can I do?

[element looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/96nAr.png)

Comment: What do you mean? You need links?

Comment: I want to get product link of "VAI ALLA SCHEDA PRODOTTO"  buttom, it seems to look like "/model.asp?p=2340487".

Comment: I don’t see any

Comment: But can see the link in elements form webpage. (I add the pic)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may utilize [RSelenium](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RSelenium/index.html) to request the intended information from the website.

Load the relevant packages. (Please ensure that the R package '[wdman](https://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/wdman/index.html)' is up-to-date.)

```
library("RSelenium")
library("wdman")
```

[Initialize](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RSelenium/vignettes/RSelenium-basics.html#what-is-a-selenium-server) the R Selenium server (I use Firefox - recommended).

```
rD <- rsDriver(browser = "firefox", port = 4850L)
rd <- rD$client
```

[Navigate](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RSelenium/vignettes/RSelenium-basics.html#basic-navigation) to the URL (and set an appropriate waiting time).

```
rd$navigate("https://www.asusworld.it/series.asp?m=Notebook#db_p=2")
Sys.sleep(5)
```

Request the intended information (you may refer to, for example, the '[xpath](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RSelenium/vignettes/RSelenium-basics.html#search-using-xpath)' of the element).

```
element <- rd$findElement(using = 'xpath', "//*[@id='series']/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/table/tbody/tr/td/div/a/div[2]")
```

Display the requested element (i.e., information).

```
element$getElementText()
[[1]]
[1] "VAI ALLA SCHEDA PRODOTTO"
```

A detailed tutorial is provided [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RSelenium/vignettes/RSelenium-basics.html) (for OS, see this [tutorial](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RSelenium/vignettes/RSelenium-saucelabs.html)). Hopefully, this helps.

Comment: Thanks, I can get "VAI ALLA SCHEDA PRODOTTO" now. How could I get it "href"(/model.asp?p=2340487) ?

Comment: What do you want exactly? Please specify.

Comment: Thanks. Actually, I only got the aforementioned information. I recommend to check the tutorial. Regularly, you can specify with element$getElementText()[[X]] (where X is a placeholder for the specific element).

Comment: As link pic, it should have 3 elements. But element$getElementText()[[3]] will occur error :(